# Can I modify a QuerySnapshot listener without unsubscribing it?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Let's assume I am listening to all items in my `bar` collection where `foo` is smaller than 5.

```
let listener = db.collection("bar").where("foo", "<", 5).onSnapshot()
```

After some user input I actually want to listen to all items where `foo` is smaller than 7. 
 Can I modify my listener without unsubscribing it?

I know that I could do `listener()` and then set up a new listener using `.where("foo", "<", 7)` but that would mean that I would fetch **all** documents again, since that is the default behaviour for listeners. I could also set up a second listener using `.where("foo", ">", 4).where("foo", "<", 7)` and then merge the results. However, that would become messy quite quickly if the user keeps changing the criteria.

Is there any clean and maintainable solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I modify my listener without unsubscribing it?

No, it's not possible.  You will need to unsubscribe, create a new Query object, and subscribe to that new one.  Either that, or subscribe to both queries and decide what you wan to do with any duplicate documents.

Comment: Is a feature like that on the roadmap? The listener would be a lot “smarter” if I could modify them while staying subscribed and they would then only fetch the difference between the old query parameters and the new ones.

Comment: You can certainly file a feature request with Firebase support.  But I suspect something like this would not happen due to its complexity.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support